# C/C++: Add -I option automatically for indirect include using automake

Tags: c++, g++, autotools, automake

I have two projects being built using Automake.  Here are simplified versions of the Automake.amS:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/some/include_path
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libfoo.la
libfoo_la_SOURCES = foo.cpp
libegfconfig_la_LIBADD = -lxml2
```

and

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I/some/include_path # I want this to happen implicitly   
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libbar.la     
libbar_la_SOURCES = bar.cpp
libbar_la_LIBADD = $(top_builddir)/some/path/libfoo.la
```

The second file only has to specify the additional include path because bar.cpp includes foo.hpp which includes something from /some/include_path.  I would like the second project to implicitly add the additional include path based on the fact that the first project does so and is a dependency.

Is this possibly?

Answer (score 1):

Putting include paths into Makefile.am is not a good idea.  If the user has installed the headers in a non-standard location, then let the user tell the configury about that by adding the appropriate -I clause to CPPFLAGS, either on the command line to configure or in a CONFIG_SITE.  It sounds like what you really want to do is put

```
CPPFLAGS=-I/some/include_path
```

either in /usr/local/share/config.site or in $CONFIG_SITE, and not include it in the Makefile.am of either of your projects.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with Automake.

Comment: Possible? Maybe. Sensible? Perhaps not.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [pkg-config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) is usually used with autotools projects

Example:

```
gcc -o test test.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libpng)
```